# WordpPress: Error in permalink after change it

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In old site i have the permalinks like :-

```
www.domain.com/q-html.html
```

And when i change my old site into `WordPress 4.0,` I set permalink like:-

```
/%postname%/
```

Now when any user search in Google, The old link not open with him, Because its change.

What can i do now !!

.htaccess file is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting (this wasn't immediately obvious to me) that the OP is talking about switching from regular html pages to a Wordpress driven site.

Comment: It's time to hire a real developer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many pages you have, you could manually set redirects in the .htaccess file. To do this, you would put the redirect, one on each line in this format:

```
redirect /q-html.html /path/to-new-page
```

You would put this *above* the part that's already existing in your .htaccess file.

Obviously if you have many, many pages that would take a long time and may not be worth it.

Comment: i have more than 2000 pages

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, add this to the top of the .htaccess file. please give it a try and see if it works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Did you create pages with the same name? So if you have /page-example.html you should create /page-example/ in the wordpress.